# How to display multiple external webpages in html div by multiple button clicks?

Tags: jquery, html

I have created 2 buttons and showing once external webpage using  tag.
I want, for example, to show webpage1 on button-1 click and webpage2 on button-2 click.

My object tag is:

```
<object id="obj" type="text/html" data="http://127.0.0.1:8080"> </object>
```

I would appreciate the help.

Full code:

```
<div class="inner-container">

<button type="button" id="surface_btn" >B1</button>
<br>
<button type="button" id="steering_btn">B2</button>
</div>
<div class="d1">
<object id="obj" type="text/html" data="URL" name="search"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code dude.

Comment: You’ve not shared your code but I’ve answered your question in a fairly broad sense. It’s helpful, though, to include your code, so that someone can respond with a helpful, relevant answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadintodiv(page, target) {
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: page,
  success: function(data){ target.append(data);}
});
}
```

In your html ...

```
<div id=“target1”></div>
 <div id=“target2”></div>
<button onclick=‘loadintodiv(“/page1”, $(“#target1”))’></button>
<button onclick=‘loadintodiv(“/page2”, $(“#target1”))’></button>
```

This will load in the data from the pages you request into the target element.

Comment: I want to load both of these webpages in the same div.

Comment: Using one click?

Comment: @Sagar I’ve amended my answer

Comment: Okay, let me explain in detail.
On my webpage there are 2 buttons, B1 and B2.
I am using these buttons to display an external URL using <object> tag in one single div D1.
For example: When I click on B1, it should display Webpage W1 in Div D1 and when I click on B2, it should display Webpage W2 in the same Div D1 by hiding previous W1 and vice versa.

Comment: @Sagar ; Thats fair enough. Can I ask why you're using the object tag and what type of data is loaded into it? Loading the content via ajax will reduce the initial load time of the page. A simple toggle would achieve this? So, setting the objects to display:none; and using toggle() onclick would achieve this, though. So button1 click event would do $(element1).toggle() and likewise for button2.

Comment: @Sagar Sure thing. If it helps, up-vote the answer, so other people know it's a working solution.

Comment: Unfortunately It's not working for me. I don't know whats wrong

Comment: @Sagar - do you get any console errors? How exactly is it not working?

Comment: I am using Angular5. It shows an error in vendor.js.
Is there any other way I can solve my problem?
I really thank you for your time.